# How to join tow times the same table?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I need to join twice the same table how do a do it in Codeigniter?

TABLE MATCH

---

- match_id
- team_home_id
- team_away_id
- score_home
- score_away
- group_id
- round_id
- winner
- start_date
- start_time

---

TABLE TEAM

---

- team_id
- name
- code

This are the two tables I have to join. The table team has to join twice with a table match.

```php
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from('match, team')
         ->join('team AS team_a', 'match.team_home_id = team_a.team_id')
         ->join('team AS team_b', 'match.team_away_id = team_b.team_id')
         ->get()->result();
```

My result is the match and just one of the teams :/

Comment: A great tip is NEVER use evil `SELECT *`. Instead ALWAYS name (and qualify) the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, yes it is a great tip, normally I do select only what I need from the tables. Do you have a try for my problem here by any chance?

Comment: Pretty much, if you follow the advice above, any remaining problems will disappear.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't  disappear, I change my select for :
matches.score_home, matches.score_away, matches.winner, matches.start_date, matches.start_time, team_a.name, team_a.code, team_b.name, team_b.code.
And in the result is just match and team_b. If I remove team_b join I get team_a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Strawberry for your help.

On my query, I was getting always the last team joined because it looks like Codeigniter overwrites the columns with the same name, team_a.name and team_a.code are represented in the final result_array() as array key "name" and "code" the same as team_b.name and team_b.code.

So more than an alias for the tables I needed to add an alias for the columns:

```
    $this->db->select('tips.stake, tips.odd, 
    matches.score_home, matches.score_away, matches.winner, matches.start_date, matches.start_time,
    team_home.name AS team_home_name, team_home.code AS team_home_code, team_away.name AS team_away_name, team_away.code AS team_away_code');

    $this->db->from('tips');
    $this->db->join('matches', 'matches.match_id = tips.match_id');
    $this->db->join('`teams` `team_home`', 'team_home.team_id = matches.team_home_id');
    $this->db->join('`teams` `team_away`', 'team_away.team_id = matches.team_away_id');

    $query = $this->db->get();
```